# How to make adjustments to a PVC raincoat?

Tags: medium-selection, plastic, clothing

I have a raincoat made of PVC that I’d like to make some adjustments to: adding more buttons or other ways of attachment (it is full-length but it has buttons only to the knee); adding a string at the bottom (to prevent too much pressure on the last button); and perhaps a pocket.

The problem is that I’m not sure how to treat the material: The acetone from the general glue for rubber would most likely melt it (I've tried it on a similar, if not the same, material before) and if I sew it the PVC would tear easily. The original adjustments seem to be made through some kind of heat-and-pressure process that cannot be duplicated without the proper machine.

[image]

The solution I came up with was to sew a small patch of cloth on the inside area I want to treat and then treat it like a cloth, but that seems a bit heavy-handed. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Have you tried electric clothing irons, curling irons or hair straighteners? Most modern versions are Teflon coated and have wide temperature ranges. Using a smooth, warm smooth surface as the anvil, the tip of a curling iron or the edge or point of a clothing iron pressed down for several seconds might be worth trying if you have some scrap to practice on. Temperature, pressure and timing should be the only important factors.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend you head to a camping supply store
 (like REI or Academy ) and pick up some tent repair tape.
 Its usually rip-stop nylon with adhesive on the back.
It will reinforce the pvc so you can add buttons etc.